# Full page cache and developer restrictions

Tags: ee-1.13, full-page-cache, inline-translations

When you have the full page cache enabled the developer restrictions are only checked for the first user to hit the page. Then they are cached and never checked again for other users.

I know that this kind of makes some sense to develop it in this way but does mean that you cannot safely enable inline translations or other items for specific ip addresses while the FPC is enabled.

Does anyone have a work around for such an issue?

It can be solved by disabling FPC and simply using the normal block cache while your are working with translations, but this is not always ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly for me the official magento support response is.

> This behavior you are seeing is to be expected

They recommend disabling all cache when working with inline translations, which to me is not ideal when working with a live shop system :(

*Note: On the plus side this is not an issue with Magento 2.*